# Access angular config from inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

For my wordpress rest api to work I have added http headers(nonce) inside the config.

Now I want to change the nonce code from inside a controller but have no idea how to do it.

I need to change the nonce code below

Main.js

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([function() {
    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            //add nonce to avoid CSRF issues
            config.headers['X-WP-Nonce'] = myLocalized.nonce;

            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

The data is the new nonce code that I want to use.

testCtrl.js

```
.success(function(data) {

    myLocalized.nonce = data;
    $state.go('account', {});
});
```

functions.php

```
function my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts', '/wp-content/themes/privatebridge/assets/js/scripts.js');

    wp_localize_script(
        'my-scripts',
        'myLocalized',
        array(
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
            )
    );
}
```

results in the frontend

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var myLocalized = {nonce":"233b70dbda"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: What is your `myLocalized`? Is it a variables under `window` or angular `config`? Can you post more of your testCtrl?

Comment: can you please elaborate where your `myLocalized` comes from ?

Comment: My bad, forgot to add that. I updated the question.